# how to choose Region Of Intrest in a 3D matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, 3d, readfile

I am new to c++.
I want to read a raw file with unsigned 16 bit data
it is a 3d grayscale image
i use visual studio to read ,process and save raw data .
then I use matlab to read the final raw data to check output image.
now I have some problem with choose the ROI of the 3d image.

here is the code I use 
when I choose the ROI,the output image goes wrong

```
using namespace std;
uint16_t image[256][256][83];
uint16_t lowbyte[256][256][83];
uint16_t highbyte[256][256][83];
uint16_t I2[256][256][83];
uint16_t III[256][256][83];
uint16_t MOD[256][256][83];
uint16_t MAX = 0;
uint16_t MIN = 0;
uint16_t temp;

double MAX2 = 0;
double MIN2 = 0;
double I22[256][256][83];
unsigned char I3[256][256][83];
unsigned char num[255];

const int x11 = 112, x22 = 143, y11 = 82, y22 = 125, z11 = 33, z22 = 65;

int main()
{


    FILE *f0 = fopen("d:\\PET11.raw", "r");
    fread(image, sizeof(uint16_t), 256 * 256 * 83, f0);
    fclose(f0);


    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++){
            for (int k = 0; k < 83; k++){
                lowbyte[i][j][k] = image[i][j][k] % 256;

                highbyte[i][j][k] = image[i][j][k] / 256;
                I2[i][j][k] = lowbyte[i][j][k] * 256 + highbyte[i][j][k];

                if (I2[i][j][k] > MAX)
                    MAX = I2[i][j][k];
                if (I2[i][j][k] < MIN)
                    MIN = I2[i][j][k];

            }
        }
    }




    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++){
            for (int k = 0; k < 83; k++){
                I22[i][j][k] = (double)I2[i][j][k];

            }
        }
    }
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++){
            for (int k = 0; k < 83; k++){
                if ((i >= x11) && (i <= x22)){
                    if ((j >= y11) && (j <= y22)){
                        if ((k >= z11) && (k <= z22)){
                            count = count + 1;
                            if (I2[i][j][k] > MAX)
                                MAX = I2[i][j][k];
                            if (I2[i][j][k] < MIN)
                                MIN = I2[i][j][k];


                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++){
            for (int k = 0; k < 83; k++){
//////////choose ROI of 3D image////////
                    if ((i >= x11) && (i <= x22) && (j >= y11) && (j <= y22) && (k >= z11) && (k <= z22))
//////////////////
                    I3[i][j][k] = (I22[i][j][k] - (double)MIN)*(255 / ((double)MAX - (double)MIN));
                else
                    I3[i][j][k] = I22[i][j][k];

                if (I3[i][j][k] > MAX2)
                    MAX2 = I3[i][j][k];
                if (I3[i][j][k] < MIN2)
                    MIN2 = I3[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }
    FILE *image3 = fopen("d:\\PET3.raw", "wb");
    for (int i = 0; i <256; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j< 256; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k< 83; k++)
            {
                fwrite(&I3[i][j][k], sizeof(unsigned char), 1, image3);

            }


        }
    }

    fclose(image3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your first problem is the the call should be `fopen("d:\\PET11.raw", "rb")`.  It's a binary file, not a text file, and you need to tell fopen that.

Comment: Also value of MIN variable as I suppose will always equal to zero

Answer (score 0):

Like @Martin said, you need to open the file as binary: `fopen("d:\\PET11.raw", "rb")`.

You're initializing `MIN` as zero. You should initialize it to 65535.
Also, `MAX2` and `MIN2` seem to be not needed.

For the values outside of the region of interest, the assignment `I3[i][j][k]=I22[i][j][k]` is suspicious. It assigns a double in the range `0 - 65535.0` to an unsigned char, which is just wrong. Perhaps you want to set it to zero instead?

Comment: thank a lot !
I modified my code ,but the output image still wrong.
Is there any problem when I choose the ROI?

Comment: Try to set the roi to be the entire image and see if this produces a good result. If this is the case then your bug is indeed in roi selection.